# iPhone not sending / recieving links

Tags: messages, ios, iphone

I've noticed that when I send a text with a link to or from my iPhone, the recieving phone does not display the link, but displays all other text. I'm not sure if this is affected by iMessage. In any case, is there a way for me to fix this problem?

I have the iPhone 6 with iOS 8.4

Comment: What is the link?

Answer (score 1):

I find the same topic in this post in Apple forum, you can have a look. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6830336?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.